# Create Foreign Key Option for Dropdown and Return to Parent View in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I apologize if this is a newb question. I'm more experienced with Windows forms and just getting started with MVC.  I have a class called *PackagedProduct* which consists of a *Package* and a *Product* that are selected via drop down list and represented by their own models.

[PackagedProduct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUVeW.png)

Sometimes though, the *Product* may not exist yet so I have an ActionLink that directs to the Create action of *Product*.
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New Product", "Create", "Products");

[Product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OncVx.png)

How can I allow the user to create the new *Product*, but when the create button is pressed to return to the PackagedProduct view where it originated with the existing data still populated(in this case UPCCode and Package)? The *PackagedProduct* won't have been created yet because it is missing required data until the correct *Product* is created so I can't just pass back the PackagedProductID. Thoughts?

Comment: Use a modal form for creating thew new product and submit it using ajax to a method that returns the new `ID` of that product. Then in the ajax success callback, add a new option to the dropdownlist based on the products ID and name.